# What language text in columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, text, localization

need help on what language text(two language) in columns in MySQL? DB consist of large number rows with multilanguage text in columns. How to do that? Encoding: UTF-8

Comment: I read it three times, but I still got no idea what you mean.

Comment: in UTF-8 table cells text in two languages: ukrainian and lithuanian(in one cell one language, in other cell another language). how to check that all symbols in cell are from national alphabet?